# Issue in creating anchor peer for the organization

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

I had created a network with two organization(Org1,Org2) in the channel using the fabric version 1.4.4.I have added one more organization to the channel.After adding the new organization to the channel,I am trying to update anchor peer based on this reference  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html#updating-the-channel-config-to-include-an-org3-anchor-peer-optional .

But it raises error while trying to sign the update transaction using Org3.

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing 
channel 'masterchannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for 
[Group]  /Channel/Application not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 1 sub- 
policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 2 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be 
satisfied
```

I tried to sign the transaction using one more org(org 2) in the network. And it raises another error as follows.

```
 Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- error applying config update to existing 
 channel 'mychannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: invalid 
 mod_policy for element [Group]  /Channel/Application/Org3: mod_policy not set
```

I am attaching the configtx.yaml regarding the Application capabilities.

```
       Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
           V1_4_2: true
           V1_3: false
           V1_2: false
           V1_1: false
```

Could anyone help me to resolve the error in anchor updation?

Answer (score 0):

The above errors are due to the invalid policy definition in the channel configuration.

The policies for the org is defined in configtx.yaml file as follows:-

```
    Organizations:
      - &Org3
          Name: Org3MSP
          ID: Org3MSP
          MSPDir: 'crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.co/msp'
          Policies:
               Admins:
                  Type: Signature
                  Rule: "OR('Org3.admin')"
```

The anchor peer update is an update to Org3, so we only need the signature of the Org3's admin for the configuration update as per the policy defined in configtx.yaml file.

The mod_policy error was due to the invalid name for the Org3 we mentioned in the channel’s application groups field.

We have to use the name of the org we defined in the configtx.yaml file  in the
channel’s application groups field.

I have replaced the name Org3 to Org3Msp(Org name in configtx.yaml) to resolve the error.

```
jq '.channel_group.groups.Application.groups.**Org3MSP**.values += {"AnchorPeers": 
{"mod_policy": "Admins","value":{"anchor_peers": [{"host": 
"peer0.org3.example.com","port": 11051}]},"version": "0"}}' config.json > 
 modified_anchor_config.json
```